# addclass if search field has value: Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-class

I have a search input field and a listbox,

```
    <input type="text"  class="inputSearch" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchRoleOne"/>
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>                                                         
    <select multiple class="listMutiple top5" ng-model="selectedRoleValue">
        <option ng-selected="selectrole" ng-repeat="role in roles | filter:searchRoleOne" value="{{role}}">{{role}}</option>      
    </select>
```

I need to addclass say

```
    .addClear{
        background: url(../images/Close.png) no-repeat right -10px center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right 5px center;
    }
```

whenever there is text, i should happen on change function. And on clicking the .addClear class search field should get empty and so does the ng-model.

How can i do this?

I tried using `ng-class="{'addClear': searchRoleOne}"` in search field. It isn't working properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply you can try with this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pankaj_287/nzPJD/8/) here

```
ng-class="{'addClear': searchRoleOne.length > 0}"
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: It is not reflecting instantly. After typing when i click somewhere else only it is getting updated

Comment: @ErmaIsabel updated fiddle..just class name are changed
http://jsfiddle.net/pankaj_287/nzPJD/8/

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ng-class="{addClear: searchRoleOne.length}"
```

This should work, see fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5613/

what version of angular you using?

Comment: It is working. How can i revert it? On clicking addClear, remove search field text and update the filter?

Comment: <button ng-click="searchRoleOne = ''"></button> like this?

Comment: Not sure what addClear is. If you create or edit the fiddle and let me know if you still have probs

Comment: I updated the fiddle. Please check. When i click on that close image i need to remove the "addClear" class and empty the search text